# can't update the state in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I have some issue with State can't set,
when I press the button the state is set "loading: true" but when I have some error with Auth I need to set state "loading: false" as I write in the cases, to back into the Login screen but *stuck* in the **LOADING** !!
the error is

[image: stuck]

> "(id: 0):
>   TypeError: this.setState is not a function"

**NOTE** I'm using react native firebase 
this is my code |

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput
} from "react-native";
import styles from "../Style/styles";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import SvgComponent from "../components/Icons";
import Loading from "./Loading";

class SignIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      loading: false,
      validations: {
        emailValid: "",
        passwordValid: ""
      }
    };
  }
  signInUser = (_email, _password) => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    try {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors .
          let errorCode = error.code;
          let errorMessage = error.message;
          switch (errorCode) {
            case "auth/wrong-password":
              alert("Wrong password.");
              this.setState({ loading: false });
              break;
            case "auth/invalid-email":
              alert(" Email address is not valid.");
              this.setState({ loading: false });
              break;
            case "auth/user-disabled":
              alert(" Email address is disabled.");
              this.setState({ loading: false });
              break;
            case "auth/user-not-found":
              alert(" no user corresponding to the given email.");
              this.setState({ loading: false });
              break;
            default:
              this.setState({ loading: false });
              alert("Please, Check your Connection");

              break;
          }
          alert("An|" + error);
          console.log(errorMessage);
        });
      this.setState({ loading: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.toString());
    }
  };
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading === true) {
      return <Loading />;
    } else {
      return (
        <ScrollView padder scrollEnabled={true}>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" keyboardVerticalOffset={70}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              {/* Start Head Section */}
              <Text style={[styles.redWord, { fontSize: 35 }]}>Sign In</Text>
              <View style={styles.logoSection}>
                <SvgComponent />
              </View>
              {/* End Head Section */}

              {/* Start Form Section */}
              <View style={styles.inputSection}>
                <Text
                  style={[styles.borderLeftInput, { top: 8, height: "66%" }]}
                />
                <TextInput
                  placeholder="Email"
                  autoCapitalize="none"
                  keyboardType="email-address"
                  style={styles.textInput}
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                  returnKeyType="next"
                  returnKeyLabel="next"
                  ref={input => (this._email = input)}
                  onSubmitEditing={() => this._password.focus()}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.inputSection}>
                <Text
                  style={[styles.borderLeftInput, { top: 8, height: "66%" }]}
                />
                <TextInput
                  secureTextEntry
                  placeholder="Password"
                  autoCapitalize="none"
                  style={styles.textInput}
                  onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                  value={this.state.password}
                  returnKeyType="done"
                  returnKeyLabel={"done"}
                  ref={input => (this._password = input)}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.handleErrors}>
                <Text style={[styles.redWord, styles.handleErrorsText]}>
                  {this.state.validations.passwordValid}
                </Text>
              </View>
              {/* End Other inputs Sections */}

              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.signInUser(this.state.email, this.state.password);
                }}
              >
                <Text style={styles.TextButton}>Sign In</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default SignIn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `catch(function(error) {})` in to an arrow function to get `this` context

```
.catch((error) => {
   //...
   this.setState({ ... });
})
```

anonymous function has it's own context ... in order to get a reference to the parent context, we need to manually bind it. unlike arrow functions ... which is automatically bound to the parent context cause it does not have its own `this`

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not
>   present in current scope they end up finding this from its enclosing
>   scope.

source: MDN

Comment: OH, it's right!, but can you explain why ES5 Function doesn't work here?

Comment: anonymous function has it's `own context` ... in order to get a reference to the parent context in it, we need to manually bind it.

unlike arrow functions ... which is automatically bind to the parent context

Comment: Greate, Thank you